# Django Can I show one value in html without for loop?

Tags: django

I want to show data from view in html. This is views.py

views.py

```
def addDeviceForm(request):

    key=request.GET['key']
    device=Device.objects.filter(key=key)
    data = {'device':device}
    return render(request,'add_form.html', data)
```

I try to show one data in html file like but it's not display value.

```
<b>{{ device.key }}</b>
```

If I show data with for like this code it have no problem.

```
{% for device in device %}
<b>{{ device.key }}</b>
{% endfor %}
```

I edit views.py like this.

```
    key="001"
    device=Device.objects.filter(key=key)
    data = {'device':device,'key':key }
    return render(request,'add_form.html', data)
```

And show in html like this.

```
{{ key.key }}
```

It still not show value.

Can I show one value in html without for loop?

Comment: yes u can show one value, if u get only one value then u can show it like above

Comment: I believe this should work -> device[0].key

Comment: `device.0.key` for first object; `device.1.key` for second object; and so on...

Comment: with this statement `device=Device.objects.filter(key=key)` are you trying to fetch only a single object which already exists in database ? or multiple objects ?

Answer (score 0):

## In template

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#first
<b>{{ data.first.key }}</b>
```

## OR

If you want to make a filter which returns nth item of your object then:

- In your app create a directory `templatetags` inside that directory create a file `__init__.py` and a file with any name `filters.py`

## In filters.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def get_item(myList, index=0):
    """
    Django template filter to get nth item of list
    """
    if index < 0:
        return myList[0]
    else:
        return myList[index]
```

## In template

The filter `get_item` can be used as:
`filters` is the name of the file in `templatetags`

```
{% load filters %}
<!-- n will be item 0, 1, 2, ... -->
<b>{{ data|get_item:"n" }}
```

Comment: That's not how you use a template tag, it is data|first, not data.first

Comment: Yes but you can use both syntaxes ```data.first``` or ```data|first```

Comment: No you can't. Feel free to try it in a shell.

Comment: If you try it on this particular code and think that it works, it still doesn't. The reason it would work on this case is because it is a method of querysets. Queryset.first, not because that's how the templatetags work.

Comment: I don't know which os you are using but on windows i used it and it worked. My django version is 4.0.1

Comment: Again, it is because it is a method of queryset, you are calling queryset.first, not the templatetag first. Here, a quick demonstration. 

`template = Template("{{items.first}} -- {{items.0}} -- {{items|first}}"); context = Context(dict(items=[0,1,2,3,4])); print(template.render(context))`
 
For this it wouldn't work and it would print ` -- 0 -- 0`

`template = Template("{{items.first}} -- {{items.0}} -- {{items|first}}"); context = Context(dict(items=User.objects.all())); print(template.render(context))`

For this it would work and it would print `username -- username --username`

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_device_form(request):
    key=request.GET['key'] # you should probably use a FORM here 
    # device=Device.objects.filter(key=key) you don't need a queryset
    # and querysets are plural, they are a set of the rows, not a single row
    device = get_object_or_404(Device, key=key) # Throws 404 if obj doesn't exist
    context = {'device':device} 
    return render(request,'add_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

the filter method of a model class will always return a query set to you not an object if you want to return an object using the filter method you should use this:

```
device=Device.objects.filter(key=key).last()
```

or

```
device=Device.objects.filter(key=key).first()
```

this way you will get the last or first object of your queryset instead of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can show one value in html, you must use  *[get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get)*<sup>django-doc</sup> or better *[get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404)*<sup>django-doc</sup>.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render


def addDeviceForm(request):

    key=request.GET['key']
    device=get_object_or_404(Device,any_key_name=key)
    data = {'device':device}
    return render(request,'add_form.html', data)
```

Then, in your `template` file you will get an object `device` in which you can access all its properties.

Template file

```
<b>{{ device.any_key_name }}</b>
```

> `Note:` *[filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter)*<sup>djano-doc</sup> always returns new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters as stated in docs. So, only use it with `looping`, since you don't know whether database has 1 record or more.